# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv-python to my visual studio code in windows 10 using `python -m pip install opencv-python -U pip --user` but I always get the error. hope somebody can help me with my errors.

I tried different suggestions like putting `--user` at the end of the command line

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\sample> python -m pip --no-cache-dir install opencv-python -U pip --user
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/ad/864b2f284517249a96190fdf6b21a291d9716115d6886938ccd86afaf821/opencv_python-4.1.0.25-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (25.7MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.7MB 467kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.16.4)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\cv2\\cv2.cp37-win32.pyd'
Check the permissions.
```

hope to install it properly anyone who can help?

Comment: I already solved my own problem! What I did is that I just uninstall my Python 3.7.3 and reinstall it again.